# how to access a const shared array safe in a class

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a shared array, it is something like that

```
class Array
{
public:
   // basic array opertion like resize, operator[], etc, like std::vector
private:
   int size;
   std::shared_ptr<int> data;
};
```

It do the shallow copy in copy constrcutor and copy assigen operator.

The memory of `Array` is controlled by `std::shared_ptr` to ensure no memory leak can happen.

Now I have a class, `ArrayContainer` , it have `Array` as the member.
I need let others access the class member. but I do not want others change it. My design is follow, but it is not good.

```
class ArrayContainer
{
public:
void calculation()
{
   // do some operation on array ...
}

// it is not a safe interface, althogh const, others still can change the member
const Array &getArray() const
{
    return this->array;
}

private:
Array array;

};
```

Using my interface, one may access the member in `ArrayContainer` by follow ways.

```
// example 1: safe use array
ArrayContainer container;
const Array &array = container.getArray();
// follow using array will not influence the member in user.
```

```
// example 2: may be not safy use array
ArrayContainer container;
Array array = container.getArray();
// follow using array may modify the array in container, it is not safe.
```

My problem is:  I do not want to other's may change the member in `ArrayContainer`. What is a elegant way to access a shared array in class with safety?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess the only way to prevent modifying the original array is to return a deep copy of it in your getArray method instead of original one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `std::shared_ptr`, since you want memory leak to not happen.

I suppose you are using `std::shared_ptr<int[]> data`, and not `std::shared_ptr<int> data`;

I guess enough for you to use `std::unique_ptr`, and don't share your memory.
Anyway you need to add copy constructor to full copy array data, because in this case

```
ArrayContainer container;
Array array = container.getArray();
```

will be called copy constructor

You can do it like below

```
Array(const Array& array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size; ++i) {
        data.get()[i] = array.data.get()[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, it is the std::shared_ptr<int>, I use it like  just like int*, but we do not need to free the memory space after use. your solution must work. Is there any technique that we still make the copy constructor shared, and still can ensure safety?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, maybe other people can help you.